# Print shortcode in defined area

Tags: shortcode, templates, wysiwyg

I would like to make shortcake to work that it would be possible to print in certain areas (sidebar, footer or normally in content). In templates I have two places with `do_shortcode` function (sidebar and footer).

So basically i have shortcode:

```
function mytheme_linkcreator_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => 'http://www.google.com',
        'position' => 'sidebar',
    ), $atts )

    $output = 'i create the link here'

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'linkcreator', 'mytheme_linkcreator_shortcode' );
```

Now I would want this to work so that if user add the shortcode in WYSIWYG shortcake like this:

```
[linkcreator url="some_url" position="sidebar"]
```

then this would be only printed in my sidebar template (where i have do_shortcode for linkcreator). Like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[linkcreator]' ); ?>
```

Then again if user add this

```
[linkcreator url="some_url" position="footer"]
```

in WYSIWYG it would be only printed in footer where I have same `do_shortcode`. But if user doesn't give any position at all, then it would be print out in content only normally (the place where user placed the shortcake in WYSIWYG).

Is this possible even to do?

Comment: Even if you could get the basic logic to work it is only going to work with some themes. Load order matters, for example. Please explain what functionality you want more generally rather than the hack you are trying implement to get that functionality. What is it that you want? Not "if I abuse shortcodes can I make this work"?